# Adding up values of multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to get the value from a bunch of input text fields on a form, then check whether or not they add up to 100. I am using the below jQuery to do this, though I just get "NaN" returned - anyone know why this is? No Doubt something stupid I've missed(!)

```
var formPercentageTotal = 0;
var currentVal = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $('.percentage-validate input.three-digit').each(function(){
        currentVal = $(this).val();
        currentVal = parseInt(currentVal);
        formPercentageTotal = formPercentageTotal + currentVal;
    });
    $('.percentage-validate .percentage-current').text(currentVal);
}, 500);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6mBQ/1/)

Comment: Interesting, a fiddle will help

Comment: I suspect that you are trying to use `parseInt` on a value that is not a number - try to inspect each value in each iteration and validate that you are indeed dealing with numerical values.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Fiddle added

Comment: That makes it obvious, you get NaN only when any field is empty, that means you are not checking whether a number is there before adding it. When all your textboxes have proper numbers the result is good. Rest you can solve yourself cause you can program good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking for NaN before adding up. You might have entered a alpahabet in any of the input field. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ9Wf/1/)

Edit: You should set formPercentageTotal into `.formPercentageTotal`.

```
var formPercentageTotal = 0;
var currentVal = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $('.percentage-validate input.three-digit').each(function(){
        currentVal = $(this).val();
        currentVal = parseInt(currentVal);
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
           formPercentageTotal = formPercentageTotal + currentVal;
        }
    });
    $('.percentage-validate .percentage-current').text(formPercentageTotal);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Still getting the same result (NaN). I am completing the input fields myself, and am only entering numbers

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: @wickywills  better provide fiddle

Comment: Fiddle added - please see original post

Comment: Close, but in your fiddle, the total value keeps going up on every timer interval even if I only enter a single value in one field

Comment: Actually, I just moved the Var lines within the setInterval function and it works fine now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered, but there are some things about your code, that make it inefficient and quite error-prone. Consider this piece of code:

```
$.fn.boundForm = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        fields: ".three-digit",
        total: ".percentage-current",
        validateInput: function(item) {
            item.value = parseInt(item.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "")) || 0;
            return parseInt(item.value);
        },
        calculateTotal: function(fields) {            
            return fields.toArray().reduce(function(sum, item) {
                return sum + this.validateInput(item);
            }.bind(this), 0);
        },
        refresh: function(form) {
            form.find(this.total).text(this.calculateTotal(form.find(this.fields)));
        }
    }


    var o = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    this.each(function() {
        var $form = $(this);    
        $form.on("input", o.fields, function() {
           o.refresh($form);
        });

        o.refresh($form);
    });
};

$(".percentage-validate").boundForm();
```

This is a basic widget, that does the same thing as your code, but:

1. It includes validation method `validateInput`, that replaces any non-numbers, and return 0 if value is empty;
2. It doesn't require 'dirty checking' every time interval to determine if value has changed, so it is more efficient;
3. It is reusable - if you need to calculate some other values elsewhere - you can easily do so just by passing an object containing different selectors, methods, and whatever, and it would still work just fine, and you'd need to simply call `$("#myContainer").boundForm(myOptions)`;

All in all, that makes for much more convenient code to work with. Hope that helps.

P. S. [Here's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6mBQ/2/)

Comment: Thanks very much for this, much better way to do it! I'm actually already now forcing only numbers to be in the input field using something similar to the regex in your code. I think I might get rid of my `setInterval` though as you suggest. Much better way. +1 :)